# How to check in Oracle if table is read only?

Tags: oracle, readonly

I would like to make an ORACLE table read only. It is possible using:

`ALTER TABLE table1 READ ONLY;`

However when table1 is already read only, then altering table is causing error.

So the question is how to check if table1 is read only, and if it isn't then
then to make it read only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `user_tables`:

```
select read_only
from user_tables
where table_name = 'TABLE1'
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use dynamic SQL to execute the `ALTER` only if necessary, avoiding errors if the table already is read-only:

```
DECLARE
   vCheck   VARCHAR2 (3);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT read_only
        INTO vCheck
        FROM user_tables
       WHERE table_name = 'TABLE1';
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         vCheck := 'YES'; -- Avoid ALTER in case of TABLE1 not existing
   END;

   --
   IF vCheck = 'NO'
   THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLE1 READ ONLY';
   END IF;
END;
```